# Type for a redux action creator

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-thunk

I am currently confused by the type of my action creator in a react-redux app that I am working on. I have this action creator with types on both side of the equation and TS compiler said everything is perfect:

```
const setItem: ActionCreator<ThunkResult<void>> = (...): ThunkResult<void> => (...): void => {
  dispatch({
    ...
  });
};
```

where ThunkResult is `ThunkResult<R> = ThunkAction<R, IStoreState, null, ActionTypes>`

What is not clear for me why on the left side the returned type of the function is `ActionCreator<ThunkResult<void>>` however, on the right side it's `ThunkResult<void>`.

*Note*: I skipped args since they are not important in this question.

I am not sure whether it's misunderstanding of [TS functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#writing-the-function-type) or it's an issue in TS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can make it easier to understand for you
First, just think **ActionCreator** is a **Type** and it will be

```js
type ActionCreator<T> = (params) : T => T
// then you can defined the variable
const setItem: ActionCreator<string> = (params) : string => ""
```

Like **ThunkResult**

```js
type ThunkResult<T> = (params): T => T
// then you can defined the variable
const thunk: ThunkResult<number> = (params): number => 0
```

So, if you mix them will be like this

```js
ActionCreator<ThunkResult<void>> = (params) : ThunkResult<void> => ThunkResult<void>
// and 
ThunkResult<void> = (params):void => void
// so
ActionCreator<ThunkResult<int>> = (params): ThunkResult<void> => (params2): void => void // just replace ThunkResult<void> above with (params):void => void
```

Hope it helps

Comment: So did I get it right and basically both ActionCreator and ThunkResult have a type 'function' and not a type of returned value of those functions?

Comment: Exactly. :----)